# Keep getting an error about pygame not being initialised

Tags: python, pygame

I keep getting an error about system not being initialised. The error is about the pygame.display.update()
Where is this meant to go?

```py
import pygame #IMPORTS THE PYGAME CLASSES, METHODS AND ATTRIBUTES
from pygame.locals import * #IMPORTING ALL PYGAME MODULES
pygame.init()  #INITIALISING PYGAME

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1000, 600
WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
blue = 146,244,255 #BACKGROUND COLOUR
width  = 80 
height = 60
x = 200 #X-POSITION OF THE CHARACTER
y = 100 #Y-POSITION OF THE CHARACTER


WINDOW.blit(player1,(x,y))

def game_loop():  #WHERE THE WINDOW IS CREATED
        run = True
        while run:
            WINDOW.fill(blue)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    run = False #WE WILL QUIT THE GAME AS THE VARIABLE run IS NOW FALSE
                    pygame.quit() #IT WON'T SHOW THE MOST RECENT THING I DREW UNLESS I MANUALLY UPDATE IT
            pygame.display.update()
game_loop()
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `pygame.quit()` is called in the application loop. `pygame.quit()` deinitializes all Pygame modules and crashes all subsequent Pygame API calls. `pygame.quit()` must be the very last Pygame API call. Call `pygame.quit()` after the application loop:

```py
def game_loop():  #WHERE THE WINDOW IS CREATED
    run = True
    while run:
        WINDOW.fill(blue)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                #pygame.quit()                          <-- DELETE
            
        pygame.display.update()

    pygame.quit()                                     # <-- INSERT 
 
game_loop()
```